# Is it possible to send Mutez along with a call to an on-chain view?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, tezos

Is it possible for a Tezos smart contract to offer a "Pay per View" on-chain view that will only respond if a certain amount of Mutez is sent with the call, or are on-chain view calls always free?

Answer (score 0):

Tezos `on-chain views` do not mutate any state (storage, balances, etc.).

But it is possible to have a subscription system, where you can have an `on-chain view` that verifies if the caller has an active subscription at the current time.

**Example:**

You create a contract that contains a `view A` and a `big_map(caller: address => expiration_date: timestamp) called subscriptions` in the storage.

Then you also have an entrypoint `subscribe` that adds a given address as a subscriber for a certain period depending on the `AMOUNT` sent when calling the respective entrypoint.

Now, when the caller calls `view A,` the view can check if that `SENDER` is an active subscriber and `FAILWITH` if it is not.

Or you could also use `callback entrypoints`, which is an asynchronous approach.